# Getting gridview image in new activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gridview

Im trying to send my clicked/selected image to new activity here's my code

```
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView; 
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,HeroData.class);
                    intent.putExtra("imageID", position);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;

    }

private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic12,
        R.drawable.pic2, R.drawable.pic13,
        R.drawable.pic3, R.drawable.pic14,

};
```

}

and trying to receive it in new activity

```
Bundle bdl = getIntent().getExtras();
    int index = bdl.getInt("imageID");
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    image.setImageResource();//the problem ! how to receive the selected image
```

i want to know im sending ("imageID",position); how to get the selected image

Comment: you have to make your imageList array public static and access to it in your new Activity..

Comment: @PiyushGupta why do you need static you can convert image into bytearray and pass it using intents. or do it as Adrián Rodríguez suggested below. Adrián Rodríguez should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are sending resources, you can send the resource id instead of the index it has in the array. Something like this:

```
intent.putExtra("imageID", mThumbIds[position]);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

And in your activity:

```
Bundle bdl = getIntent().getExtras();
int imageRes = bdl.getInt("imageID");
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
image.setImageResource(imageRes);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: just right ! :D changed the sending resource to resource id !

Answer (score 1):

Use Like this...

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()   
    {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,int position, long id) 

        {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HeroData.class);



            i.putExtra("imageID", position);

             startActivity(i);


        }
    });
```

need to wright click for gridview...

Comment: `intent.putExtra("imageID", position)` is it not the same. how is different?

Comment: Put this in your MainActivity within the onCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your drawable resourses in another place, for example you can do it in resources, as string-array

```
<resources>

<string-array name="thumbs_imgs">
    <item>@drawable/pic1</item>
    <item>@drawable/pic2</item>
    <item>@drawable/pic3</item>
</string-array>

</resources>
```

and then get by index drawable what you need

```
TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.thumbs_imgs);
//get resourceid by index
mImgView1.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));
```